# M8 connectors and their coding

Tags: connector, wiring, can, canopen

A quick read on the internet shows that M8 connectors are coded.
The little info online I can find says A-coded is the most common style, typically used for sensors and actuators. B-coded is is mostly used for fieldbus connections.
This is what they look like:

[image]

[image]

What I am not understanding is why is one used for field bus and not the other? What's the difference between the two. They both have an indentation to prevent connecting incorrectly. What other reason could there be?

I need to pick a connector for CANbus and want to go with the M8 series as it is durable but wasn't sure if I should stick to B-coding or A-coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Engineers follow industrial standards.

The canonical source in this case is CANopen CiA 303-1, chapter 7.2 which specifies A type. This applies to M12. If you use M8 then go with the very same pin-out and coding. See the pic below. The square means A coding.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

M12 A-coded 5 pin is the standard cable for Canopen/Devicenet

[IEC 61076-2-101](https://www.mouser.com/pdfDocs/ernics-industrialarticle_m8m12.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

Choose the one that has most stock, most likely type A.

Comment: Yeah thats the plan at the minute. But still curious as to why one is more suited for certain applications.

Comment: If you have several connector of the same type, but different signals for different system, you don't want the user to plug the wrong cable at the wrong place and fry your system.

Comment: But that applies to both A and B coded. They both have an indentation which prevents you from plugging it incorrectly

Comment: plugging a 4-20mA signal into a fieldbus connector could be expensive.

Comment: @Hasman404 That is the point, to prevent plugging A types into B types, so you don't blow up anything.

Comment: @Justme No my question is why pick an A type or a B type. Whats the actual difference? Why do they say one is suited for field bus and the other for sensors and actuators.

Comment: @Hasman404 There is no other difference, than to prevent plugging incompatible devices together. That is why compatible devices have compatible connectors.